# SSRS user defined parameter for subreports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am new here and was wondering if anyone can help me. I am fairly new with SSRS and want to know if the following can be implemented in SSRS.

I have a Main Report that results a table from a stored procedure. The table results the following columns:

- consumed item id
- consumed item location
- consumption date
- produced item id
- produced item location
- quantity consumed

Is there a way after running the initial report, a user can pick and use one of the "produced item id" and "produced item location" result and run it through another report/sub-report?

Comment: This is called a "Drillthrough report". See the Microsoft documentation on how to do this here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/drillthrough-reports-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @AlanSchofield Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for your help